# Rotationmatrix along three axis not after another.

Tags: geometry, rotations, affine-geometry

I want to rotate the Point $P (0.5, 1, 1.5)$ along three axis by 90°. For this I am searching the transformation matrix to do this. I know about the 3 standard matrices, but when I multiply these. I get three sequential rotations.

There the 3 standard rotation matrices: [klick here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HwKIY.png). (I am not allowed to embedd images).

When I multiply these $R_z(90) \cdot R_y(90) \cdot R_x(90)$ and apply it to point $P(0.5, 1, 1.5)$:

$Rz(90) \cdot R_y(90) \cdot R_x(90) \cdot P$

I get the transformation visualized [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8dswc.png) using the red box, but I want to transform it along three axes at the same time (all 90°) as visualized by the blue box.

I am searching for the transformation matrix along all three axes at the same time.

Comment: I guess what I'm searching is a Compound Rotation along all three axis?

Comment: If you know where the vertices are supposed to end up at the end of the sequence, you can build a rotation using that information. Otherwise, you’ll have to identify the axes of rotation for the second two steps.

Comment: It's this forumla here: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Rotation_matrix_from_axis_and_angle

Comment: That formula requires you to know the rotation axis, which is basically what you’re asking for in your question.